# What is the forum engine used by both MVC CMS and TheBeerHouseExample?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

What Blog engine does [MVC CMS](http://www.mvccms.net/forums/thea-sandy-baux) and [The Beer House](http://www.thebeerhouseexample.com/forums/6/what-can-we-do-better) use?

Comment: Looking at the exception trace here (http://www.thebeerhouseexample.com/forums/posts/5/community-events-for-beer-tasting) it seems it is just written from scratch.

Comment: :) yes, I noticed the exception. But the similarity seems so obvious to me that I believe they have something in common

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Beer House is written from scratch by 3 guys for a book entitled ["ASP.NET MVC 1.0 Website Programming: Problem - Design - Solution"](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0470410957).  It was first written for ASP.NET, then ported to ASP.NET MVC.  The [source code](http://www.codeplex.com/wikipage?ProjectName=TheBeerHouse) is open source, and they invite others to utilize the framework to build other sites.  Apparently hundreds of sites have been built using their CMS, so it's possible that "MVC CMS" was as well.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, MvcCms used quite a bit of stuff from the original Beerhouse Code.  The forum being no exception.  MvcCms has done quite a bit to the forum adding things like sub threads and other odds and ends but yes they are both of similar origin.

The most important pieces that were adopted from Beerhouse were the url slug methods that allowed us to assemble the cms as a semantic engine for the urls in the form of.

category+?subcategory(?multiple)+?page